# Save which files are in which revision to recover later

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have for example files:
a.xml
b.xml
c.xml
d.xml
etc...
And I have 100 revisions.
I make something on files
a.xml in revision 50
b.xml in revision 50
c.xml in revision 100
d.xml in revision 75
Lets name this layout A
Then I make something on files:
a.xml in revision 20
b.xml in revision 100
c.xml in revision 80
d.xml in revision 40
This layout will be B
I want to switch between A and B easy, is there any way to save in which revisions are files to update them to head, a then recover them to layout A. ? I need some way to saving which files is in which revision. Does someone know how to make it ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Read about Mixed Working Copy
2. Read about revisions in SVN (and understand meaning of "global, repository-wide revisions")
3. Read about tags in Subversion
4. Read `svn help update`

After 1-4:

- Prepare "layout A"
- Save as tag
- Prepare "layout B"
- Save as tag

Answer (score 0):

You can save diff of layout A and layout B. you can switch between them by applying the diff file you want